# how to test controllers created with angular.module().controller() in Angular.js using Mocha

Tags: unit-testing, controller, angularjs, mocha.js

I have a controller created with angular.module().controller() like in this situation

```
myModule = angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
                   .controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
                           $scope.test = 'this is a test';
                    }]);
```

now, I need to use mocha to test if my controller is working properly. In Angular there are some examples when controllers are declared as global functions ( ex. http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04 ), so they use

```
function PhoneListCtrl() {...}
.....
beforeEach(function() {
   scope = {},
   ctrl = new PhoneListCtrl(scope);
});

it('shod test whatever PhoneListCtrl does ', function() {
   expect(scope.someProp).toBe('whateverValue');
});
```

so the questions are:

1) how can I do a similar test for controllers that are declared using angular.module().controller()

2) how to do it using Mocha

Answer (score 28, accepted):

AngularJS provides mocks that make available some useful functions for dependency injection while testing.

- [module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.module)
- [inject](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject)

### Example:

*(in jasmine)*

Let's say we want to perform the first test from the [official tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02) and we have defined a controllers module. (you could namespace the module name, but I want to keep it simple)

```
var Controllers = angular.module('controllers', []);

Controllers.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.phones = [{name: "Nexus S", snippet: "Fast..."},
                     {name: "Motorola XOOM...", snippet: "The Next...."},
                     {name: "MOTOROLA XOOM...", snippet: "The Next, Next..."}];
}]);
```

Then we create a module for out app and inject it our controllers module

```
var PhonesApp = angular.module('phoneApp', ['controllers']);
```

Finally we can test it like this

```
describe('phonesApp', function() {
    describe('phoneApp controllers', function() {
        beforeEach(module('controllers'));
        describe('PhoneListCtrl', function() {
            it('should create "phones" model with 3 phones',
                inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {

                var scope = $rootScope.$new();
                var ctrl = $controller("PhoneListCtrl", {$scope: scope });
                expect(scope.phones.length).toBe(3);
            }));
        });
    });
});
```

I haven't done it in mocha, but I guess the process is similar.

Pd: I did the tutorial using CoffeeScript, here are the relevant bits https://gist.github.com/4163147

Comment: thank you for the explanation. using inject after module throws a weird error. can you please check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802837/angularjs-inject-causing-error-in-tests

Answer (score 15):

If you're using mocha, beware that there is no support for `angular.mock.module` or `angular.mock.inject` unless you've upgraded to angular-1.1.1.  I'm in the same boat, but I can't upgrade because of another issue.

I want to use mocha, because my server side tests are in mocha, and I'd prefer to have the same test framework on both sides, so I'm in a bit of a pickle.

So, if you can't use inject/module, then you can try it this way:

```
var $injector = angular.injector(['your-app-name', 'ng']),
  $controller = $injector.get('$controller'),
  $scope = $injector.get('$rootScope');

describe('my app controllers', function () {
  describe('FooCtrl', function () {
     it('should do something', function () {
        // scope can be any object you want; could be $rootScope from above
        var params = { $scope: { } },
          ctrl = $controller('FooCtrl', params);
        // TODO: test ctrl
     });
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm still having the same problem (angular.mock.inject doesn't work) in Angular 1.1.2; this workaround helped; thanks! (angular.mock.inject exists and is callable for mocha, but isSpecRunning trips over a missing queue property, so it doesn't actually work.)

Comment: Nice workaround, tried this solution and works well. But 1.1.4 version angular.mock works with mocha.

Comment: @Jimchao - yep, if you go with angular-unstable branch, they do support mocha with angular.module.mock and angular.mock.inject