# Cannot make controller tests working with AngularJS + RequireJS

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, jasmine, karma-runner

Can’t figure out how to make controller tests working. I am playing with ngStart seed project. So I forked the repository (https://github.com/Havrl/ngStart ) and want to create a very basic unit test.

My controller test file:

```
define(function() {
"use strict";
describe("the contactcontroller", function () {
    var contactController, scope;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module("contact");

        inject(["ContactController", function (_contactController) {
            contactController = _contactController;
        }]);
    });


    it("should give me true", function () {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});

});
```

But that is not working.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as answered in the following question the controller needs to be manually instantiated with a new scope:

[how to test controllers created with angular.module().controller() in Angular.js using Mocha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585964/how-to-test-controllers-created-with-angular-module-controller-in-angular-js)

Additionally the project you are using (its mine :-) ) is defining the controllers inside route definitions and not with a call to angular.controller(...).

The downside is that the controllers are not known by name to angularJS (afaik), so the code from the answer above would not work:

```
ctrl = $controller("ContactController", {$scope: scope });
```

Instead you have to load the controller explicitely with requireJS inside your test file and give the function to the $controller(..) call, like this:

```
define(["ContactController"], function(ContactController) {
"use strict";
describe("the contactcontroller", function () {
    var contactController, scope;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module("contact");

        inject(["$rootScope", "$controller", function ($rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            contactController = $controller(ContactController, {$scope: scope});
        }]);
    });

    ....
});
```