# AngularJS: inject causing error in tests

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I am unable to use `inject` in my tests.

Both `angular` and `angular-mocks` are `version 1.3.14`

I am completely lost here. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated!

This causes an error:

```
describe("factory: Account", function () {

    var $httpBackend;
    var $rootScope;
    var Account;

    beforeEach(module('app'));

    beforeEach(inject(function() {
        // $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    }));


    it("Should fetch account", function() {
    });
});
```

But if I remove inject it will pass:

```
describe("factory: Account", function () {

    var $httpBackend;
    var $rootScope;
    var Account;

    beforeEach(module('app'));

    beforeEach(function() {
        // $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    });


    it("Should fetch account", function() {
    });
});
```

In Gruntfile.js:

```
    karma: {
        unit: {
            options: {
                frameworks: ['jasmine'],
                singleRun: true,
                browsers: ['Safari'],
                files: [
                    'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
                    'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
                    'bower_components/moment/moment.js',
                    'bower_components/ckeditor/ckeditor.js',
                    'bower_components/ng-ckeditor/ng-ckeditor.min.js',
                    'app/app.js',
                    'app/**/*.js',
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the output of the test:

```
Safari 8.0.5 (Mac OS X 10.10.3) factory: Account Should fetch account FAILED
    /.../bower_components/angular/angular.js:63:32
    /.../bower_components/angular/angular.js:4120:30
    forEach@/.../bower_components/angular/angular.js:323:24
    loadModules@/.../bower_components/angular/angular.js:4081:12
    createInjector@/.../bower_components/angular/angular.js:4007:22
    workFn@/.../bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2353:60
```

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same problem.  It was also a dependency issue, like @user2755599, and this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/37946833/2908670 helped me out.

Basically, error messages might be hidden by PhantomJS.  Switch to a browser like Chrome for running the tests to get more information.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should write it like this:

```
describe("factory: Account", function () {
    var $httpBackend;
    var $rootScope;
    var Account;

    beforeEach(module('app'));

    beforeEach(function(_$httpBackend_) {
         $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    });

    it("Should fetch account", function() {
    });
});
```

You need to declare `$httpBackend` before using it.

Answer (score 0):

It worked if you removed the inject because basically then it doesn't do anything.

You need the inject, and the `$httpBackend` should be passed as a parameter wrapped in underscores:

```
describe("factory: Account", function () {

    var $httpBackend;
    var $rootScope;
    var Account;

    beforeEach(module('app'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_) {
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    }));


    it("Should fetch account", function() {
    });
});
```

Comment: this is not obligatory, only for convenience if you want to use the variable with the same name again, as in your example

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was simply due to loading angular-mocks twice.

The project was written using Browserify and the original developers included mocks in the vendor.js bundle as well as loading it into Karma via it's config. Once I removed mocks from the bundle and only let Karma load it I was good to go.