# Angular Unit test fails when i try to inject a service

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a angular where i want to test my controllers and services with karma and jasmine. I wrote some tests and they worked. Then i did some big changes to my angular project. 
Now my tests are all failing and i can't figure out why. I commented everything out in my tests and just wanted to check if the `$controller` service gets loaded. But not even this works.

My module definition:

```
angular.module('cManagement', [
    'angular-multi-select',
    'ngCookies',
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'pascalprecht.translate',
    'ngIdle'
])
```

Here is my test:

```
use strict';
describe("cManagement", function() {

 beforeEach(module('cManagement'));

 it('should exist', inject(function($controller){
 }));
});
```

My Karma config:

```
module.exports = function(config){
    config.set({

        basePath : '',
        reporters: ['progress', 'junit'],
        files : [
            'node_modules/angular/angular.js',
            'node_modules/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
            'node_modules/angular-multi-select/dist/angular-multi-select.js',
            'node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
            'node_modules/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap.js',
            'node_modules/angular-translate/dist/angular-translate.js',
            'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            'assets/plugins/angular-idle/angular-idle.js',
            'app/app.module.js',
            'app/components/login/*',
            'app/**/*'
        ],

        singleRun : true,

        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

        browsers : ['PhantomJS'],

        plugins : [
                'karma-jasmine',
                'karma-junit-reporter',
                'karma-phantomjs-launcher'
                ],

        junitReporter : {
            outputDir: 'test_out',
            userBrowserName: false
        }

    });
};
```

Here is the error i get:

> INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.37 server started at
>   http://localhost:9876/
>        INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
>        INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket  7iIMKn57rTEEJqjikf2o with id 71013283
>       PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) cManagement should exist FAILED
>   /home/chris/IdeaProjects/campaignManagement/node_modules/angular/angular.js:4527:53
>         forEach@/home/chris/IdeaProjects/campaignManagement/node_modules/angular/angular.js:321:24
>         loadModules@/home/chris/IdeaProjects/campaignManagement/node_modules/angular/angular.js:4487:12
>         createInjector@/home/chris/IdeaProjects/campaignManagement/node_modules/angular/angular.js:4409:30
>         workFn@/home/chris/IdeaProjects/campaignManagement/node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2799:60
>       PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 2 (1 FAILED) (0.006 secs / 0.007 secs)

Every hint is appreciated.

Comment: Can you try `inject` in a separate `beforeEach` block? `beforeEach(inject(function($controller){ }));`

Comment: Maybe just a typing error but "use strict';" should be "use strict;"

Comment: And you have an extra tick near `use strict`

Comment: Moving into a seperate beforeEach block doesn't change anthing. Neither does correcting the use strict typo.

Comment: I'm actually getting this exact same issue.

Comment: Hey, I figured out my issue. Change the karma server to Chrome or another browser. PhantomJS seems to hide errors like this for some reason. I'm betting the real reason will show up if you use Chrome.

Comment: Thank you very much. After i changed the browser to chrome, i have got the exact error message. I was missing a dependency...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most probably you have a dependency issue -maybe a module that cannot be loaded- but you can't tell exactly which one because PhantomJS sometimes *hides* relevant info from the error message.

The solution is to change (temporarily) the testing browser to Chrome or any other non-headless browser to see exactly what's wrong.

eg: you should change in Karma config or `Gruntfile.js` or what have you:

the line `browsers: ['PhantomJS'],`

into something like: `browsers: ['Chrome'],`

and then you should be able to see the error and correct it. Afterwards, you can switch it back to PhantomJS.

*Note: Just placing for posterity the workaround as per **@snowe2010**'s comment (the question didn't have an answer so people may disregard the solution)*